# Не работают точки остановки в Visual Studio: нет загруженных символов

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Хочу перенести свой проект с QT Creator на Visual Studio.

Мой проект представляет из себя dll-библиотеку на C++, которая вызывается из exe-файла. Я создал проект динамической библиотеки, перенес код из .h и .cpp файлов и добавил к решению exe-файл, который эту библиотеку должен использовать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запустил - запустилось. Но на точки остановки cpp-файлов библиотеки пишет, что нет загруженных символов.

Посмотрел настройки:

- Набор символов  - **Использовать набор символов юникода** (пробовал ставить многобайтовую - то же)
- Компоновщик/Отладка/Создавать отладочную информацию - выбрал **DEBUG: FULL** - чтоб наверняка
- Ниже пункт **создавать файл базы данных программы** - `$(OutDir)$(TargetName).pdb` - пробовал указывать путь, в котором лежит exe-шник, не помогло

Файл pdb создается и исправно лежит в каталоге с dll, пробовал его копировать в папку с программой. Пробовал копировать программу в папку с dll и pdb. То же

На этом я как-то уже осекся

Собственно вопрос: возможно ли как-то в Visual С++ отлаживать библиотеку через запуск программы, использующую эту библиотеку подобно qt creator или это непобедимая проблема?

Comment: Что значит "добавил к решению exe-файл"? Как запустил? Как должна подргужаться эта библиотека? Где пишет?

Comment: А может правильнее будет написать "точки останова", или это не имеет значения?

Comment: @VTT, добавил скриншот дерева проектов. Из exe-файла вызывается extern функция библиотеки, имеющая си-интерфейс. Собственно, она и задействует весь остальной функционал этой dll. Приложение назначил автозапускаемым проектом. Запускаю через F5

Comment: Вы смотрели это? [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130417/how-to-debug-a-referenced-dll-having-pdb)

Comment: Посмотрите откуда грузится dll. Если по пути откуда загружен dll нет pdb или pdb не соответсвует dll то в этом смысле конечно нет загруженных символов. В конечном итоге должен грузится тот dll, который Вы собрали из VS. Посмотрите нет ли такого же dll где то по установленным путям или в каталоге Windows например.

Comment: @AndreySv, проверил. pdb создаются с dll и exe. Каждый лежит в своем каталоге. dll называется ini.dll. В системе таких нет. Пробовал инструкцию отсюда https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-from-a-dll-project?view=vs-2019 и коннектиться к уже запущенному процессу. Даже символы с серверов майкрософт полторы минуты грузились, но в итоге та же ошибка. Может быть, дело в том, что я пытаюсь присоединиться к .NET приложению? Потому что к обычным нативным из диспетчера устройств если коннектчусь, то точки останова включаются (экспериментировал)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, спасибо. Попробовал несколько новых для меня советов: очистил кэш символов, убрал точное соответствие версий, выключил "только мой код". Единственное, что у меня не совпадает - это фреймворк. Но я не могу это обойти. Ну и собственно сейчас при запуске microsoft загружает с сервером новый пакет символов, но - судя по описанию - они все для этого exe, а мне не надо отлаживать exe. Мне надо отлаживать свою dll... Вотс. Пока писал, докачались символы - результат тот же

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk, переписал со студии. Там они так переведены. В qt были "останова" - думаю, значения не имеет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычные нативные exe-файлы запускаются и позволяют производить отладку dll без проблем при подсоединении к их процессу, так и при добавлении в проект. Вопрос остался к .NET приложениям

Способа отлаживать .NET-приложение из dll-проекта C++, как и саму dll, я так и не нашел. Но я пошел от обратного, последовав этой [инструкции](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code?view=vs-2019):

1. Создал проект для классического .NET приложения
2. Включил отладку машинного кода в свойствах проекта
3. Сделал вызов функции из dll в си-интерфейсе (сам проект можно даже не добавлять в решение)

Отладка dll заработала без проблем